# Proof the Associative Property of H-group

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, homotopy-theory

I would like to prove the following proposition:

---

Let $X$ and $Y$ be based topological spaces and let $[X,Y]$ be the set of homotopy classes of based maps $X\to Y$. If for every $X$, $[X,Y]$ is a group with unit the homotopy class of the constant map and that $f^*:[X',Y]\to[X,Y]$ is a homomorphism, where $f:X\to X'$, then $Y$ is an H-space.

---

My attempt is, let the product of $[Y,Y]$ be denoted by "$+$" (though it may not be commutative) and let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be the two natural projections from $Y\times Y$ to $Y$, then define $m$ and $i$ by $$[m]=[p_1]+[p_2]$$ and $$[i]=-[id_Y].$$

Then I can prove all conditions in the definition of H-group except that $$m(m\times id)\simeq m(id\times m):Y\times Y\times Y\to Y.$$

---

My attempt:

$[m(m\times id)]=(m\times id)^*([m])=(m\times id)^*([p_1]+[p_2])=(m\times id)^*([p_1])+(m\times id)^*([p_2])=[p_1(m\times id)]+[p_2(m\times id)],$

and similarly

$[m(id\times m)]=[p_1(id\times m)]+[p_2(id\times m)].$

But how to proceed? How can I use the associate property of $[Y\times Y,Y]$?

Comment: This is a Yoneda lemma argument. More generally, in any category, if $G$ is an object such that $\text{Hom}(-, G)$ naturally has a group structure, then $G$ is a group object. Applied here you conclude that $Y$ is a group object in the pointed homotopy category, which is a bit stronger than being an H-space.